# How to clean ConcurrentHashMap in thread safe way

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a ConcurrentHashMap oricginalCahce in which mulptile threads are writing concurrently from many places of the code.
I have to flush the map periodically so I do below I create a temporary copy of Map and clean the origianl Map

```
void flushcopyOfOriginalCache(String queueName) {
        Map<Integer, Date> copyOfOriginalCache = null;
        Object lock = getLastscheduledTimeUpdateLock(queueName);
        //this lock is not aquired at the time of writing as the writing in taking place in many places of the code
        synchronized (lock) {
        //rechecking for whether expired or not
            if (isOrigCacheExpired(queueName)) {
                log.info("origCache Expired for queue {}", queueName);
                if (orignalCache.containsKey(queueName)) {
                    copyOfOriginalCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(
                            orignalCache.get(queueName));
                    //How safe is below clean ??? as parallel writes might be going on orignalCache!
                    orignalCache.get(queueName).clear();
                }

            }
        }

        if (copyOfOriginalCache == null || copyOfOriginalCache.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        //Below is expenssive DB operations on with data in copyOfOriginalCache  

        }
```

How to make sure that this clean method should not delete entries which is par alley being written. Please guide.

Comment: Have you considered using guava caching since they have already implemented that?

Comment: No. As I am working preexisting code so trying to use that only. But I will take a look at guava cache if nothing works.

Comment: Guava cache works like a hashmap but comes with all the features you require. If you want your clear not to coincide with your write, you need to synchronise both those method on the same object. Is your code correct? copyOfOriginalCache has a key-type of Integer, yet you retrieve the original one with a string as key. I am not sure why you create the copy either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually  copyOfOriginalCache  is the copy of value of OriginalCache. The value itself is a Map of type  Map<Integer, Date>

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Alternatively, to make it work with guava and compatible with your code, you could create your own hashmap implementation that simply wraps a guava cache. They implement most of the methods of a hashmap anyway, they just created a new interface to make it clear that it is a cache and not an interface. Guava is also well proven in production and test and used across many enterprise products. Why reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: The `clear()` method of ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe.

Comment: @ pandaadb thanks!

Comment: @ jaco0646 So that means when we call clear on a map there is no put/get can happen ?

Answer (score 0):

For a ConcurrentHashMap you can use computeIfPresent, with a predicate `canDeleted(Value v)`

```
concurrentHashmap.forEach((key, value) -> 
    concurrentHashmap.computeIfPresent(key, (t, s) -> (canDeleted(s) ? null : s)))
```

this is threadsafe and easy to implement.